# pg_dump: how to set standard_conforming_strings=off

Tags: postgresql

I am doing a SQL dump with postgreSQL 9.1.23.

I want to set standard_conforming_strings=off

My goal is to import it into an earlier version (8.1).

I have tried setting the option in pgAdmin, but it changes it back when it does a dump.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to use an unsupported and really old version like 8.1?

Comment: My VPS is using cpanel which apparently only supports 8.1.  I'm not sure if this matters. Maybe I can upgrade the server without any problems?

Comment: Personally I'd try to find a different provider then. Offering 8.1 is simply unprofessional. That version is over 8 years old and has been out of maintenance for over 2 years now.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it in postgres.conf.

standard_conforming_strings=off